# Upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 fails

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 17.10, internet, connection

My upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 fails, saying no internet connection though my connection is well established. There was a network error when I tried to upgrade, few downloaded packages were saved and ever since this error pops up in middle of upgrade every time.

Here is the image of error message:
[image: here is the image of error message]

I am able to go this far only every time:
[image: I am able to go this far only every time(image link)]

Comment: Try `apt update`, then retry.

Comment: still the same .

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade path you want must be stepwise and involves 16.10 and 17.04, which have passed end of life. This makes it very complicated and likely to fail.

- **The best upgrade alternative would be to wait until the next LTS version** (and its first point release) 18.04.1 LTS in July or August (2018).
- Otherwise the best alternative is to backup your personal files and **make a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.10.1 from the iso file**. After the installation you can copy your personal files into the new operating system.

Comment: I am looking for a way to just reset everything and retry for upgrade, without making fresh installation.

Comment: Sorry, if you have no backup of the original system (from before your upgrade attempt), it might be very difficult or impossible to reset everything. But I think your personal files are still there and available from a live drive (booted from a USB pendrive or DVD disk).